# Mishnah Edition

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, mishna

Can someone recommend an edition of the Mishnah? I am looking for an edition that is - a) all-Hebrew b) with all the major commentators (Bartenura, Rambam, T. Yom Tov, etc.) C) printed with very clear print d) beautiful with high quality paper, and e) very accurate

Answer (score 2):

There are several:

1. The [Zecher Chanoch](https://www.eichlers.com/mishnayos-zecher-chanoch-medium13-vol.html) set (specifically the new print version)
   [image]
2. There is the Oz Vehadar Mishnayos which include the Bartenura and Ikkar Tosafos Yom Tov e.g. [here](https://www.judaicaplace.com/mishnayos-talmidim-oz-vehadar-nashim-menukad-hardcover/mlnas/)
3. [The Hamefuar Yefei Einayim](https://www.eichlers.com/mishnayos-hamefuar-yefei-einayim-shisha-sidrei-mishnah-13-vol-set-hardcover.html) set which has quite a comprehensive list of mefarshim see below:
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: The Zecher Chanoch edition looks perfect. Is that your top recommendation? Do you own that one and have experience learning from it?

Comment: Yes I have the older version from when I was barmitzvah and still use it today!

Comment: Wonderful, thank you.

Comment: Zecher Chanoch is the classic.

Comment: FYI, pdf versions of the זכר חנוך volumes (use that title for search) are available on Hebrewbooks.org